# Getting error , Sandbox exited with unexpected code: {"code":null,"signal":"SIGKILL"} during Vercel deployment

Tags: deployment, backend, mern, vercel

I'm try to  deploy my MERN stack project in vercel. During Building it do not shows any error but after waiting 15-17 minute  I'm not getting any final link but a error,  Sandbox exited with unexpected code.

THis is how I connected the frontend with the backend.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/client/dist")));

app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "client", "dist", "index.html"));
});
```

error in vercel

`Sandbox exited with unexpected code: {"code":null,"signal":"SIGKILL"}` This is the error.
And I'm not getting final link for my website